# CSV file shows '?' instead of text

Tags: excel, csv

I have a following problem:
Yesterday I created a csv file and wrote there down some text using unicode characters. I saved it as a usual csv file, not a utf-8 csv file. Today, when I opened it, my text, that was written in non-latin alphabet, looks like this:

[image]

Is there any chance to get my text back? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You wrote unicode data as ascii to a file. That's not a good idea. What does this file look like if you open it in a tool like notepad++? If it's all question marks in there too, then it's safe to assume that for every multi-byte unicode character you HAD in excel, excel wrote out a literal `?` into the file and that data is now lost. If, however, you see something besides `?`, then there may be a chance for recovery.

Comment: @JNevill It's the same(( English words are displayed correctly. But unicode characters are now just question marks

Comment: Your data was lost.  Pull the original data source, and retain encoding before saving next time.  This file is unrecoverable as it stands.

Comment: Checking back in on this one. OP, I'm sorry for your loss. :(

Comment: Still thanks for trying